# Camel: how to enable/disable endpoints using CamelContext

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am routing messages to a bunch of endpoints using Camel 2.14.1, for example:

```
from(...)
...
.to(monitoringEndpointId, broadcastEndpointId);
```

I want to to dynamically enable/disable these endpoints/routes during runtime. So far I've tried to use [`CamelContext`](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.14.0/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html)'s `stopRoute` and `suspendRoute` methods, for example:

```
camel.suspendRoute(broadcastEndpointId)
```

But this results in the following exception:

```
An unknown exception occurred:
org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://broadcast]. Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:NB137-38323-1460630272896-5:1:1:1:1356]]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:47)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:416)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:685)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:623)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:591)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:246)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1031)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

So this actually works, but the logs are full of these exceptions. Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You can configure your route to be dynamic : http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give route id to your route as shown below -

```
from("activemq:queue:test")
.routeId("myrouteid")
.to("file:///hello");
```

Then you can use suspend and resume route using camel context -

```
camelContext.suspendRoute("myrouteid") or camelContext.resumeRoute("myrouteid")
```

For more information go through http://camel.apache.org/lifecycle.html

Comment: `#suspendRoute()` is exactly what I tried and that is why I get the `DirectConsumerNotAvailableException`. Is there any option to ignore/swallow that exception without losing it's purpose?

Comment: suspendRoute is used to suspend the full route. If you want to do dynamic routing go for recipient list EIP or Dynamic Router EIP. 
[Recipient List](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html), [Dynamic Router](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html)

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be using Filter. Then 'switch' the endpoint on and off using properties:

```
    <filter>
        <simple>${properties:endpoint1.isEnabled}</simple>
        <to uri="direct:endpoint1"/>
    </filter>
```